# how can I protect a data segment in an exe file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I build an exe file from a solution in a VS.2012, after that I using any HEX-Viewer I can see at the end of file the pure data characters values. Ex:

```
"SELECT user FROM NOMEN WHERE iduser=",
```

"Determinar los valores a visualizar:", etc, etc.
(means: Determine the values ​​to display)

How can I encode, protect, encrypt this segment data?

thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: not really a solution (as theres not really any good solution) but some thoughts here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018215/how-to-obfuscate-string-constants

Think of this: If you do encrypt your sensitive strings (which is of course a posibility) how will you decrypt them without exposing the decryption key in the decompiled code? You add a layer of difficulty  but if someone really wants to read your strings and have access to your binary, they will.

Comment: There isn't any point in hiding it, the user can find out what your queries look like by using a network sniffer or using the tooling available in the dbase engine to see what is executing.  If this is important to hide then keep it in a locked server room that's only accessible by those with a security clearance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Stored Procedure and a command object with parameters.  At least the actual query wouldn't be in your app.